# Is react-redux required to use with redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using React-native and Redux, but my app is very small and simple, so I thought that redux-react isn't necessary overhead, so I didn't use it. I just import store whenever I need because it is a singleton anyways. But now with redux-persist I'm getting an error `"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.persistor.subscribe')"` from App.js, so I guess it might be because I don't use store Provider. Is it true?

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from './reducers/reducer';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistor };
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import RootContainer from './src/components/containers/root-container';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { persistor } from './src/configureStore';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootContainer />
      </PersistGate>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you need store anyways then, you can store data in the component state and just use cookies or localStorage

Comment: for the sake of learning

Comment: Then you would use it the right way.

Comment: React-redux is created to simplify usage of redux with react. Nowhere says that I have to use it or it won't work without it. If redux-persist is tightly coupled with react-redux, then I have to. But it is unclear from their website and this is what I'm trying to clarify. Your comments don't help.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `this.props.persistor`? Looking at the `redux-presist` library there's nothing special going on with `PersistGate` that should require something like `react-redux`. More likely is that your `persistor` instance is actually `undefined` and that's where your error starts.